# How to hide dock icon of running app on OS Big Sur

Tags: applications, big-sur, dock, icon

How can I hide the dock icon of an app that is running on Mac OS Big Sur?

I have the app "SurePlus MOTIV" running at all times as it is used to manage my microphone preferences. I barely need to touch the app as I've already configured and locked my mic preferences. If I do need access, it has a taskbar icon anyway, making the dock icon a waste of space.

I've only been able to find old guides that no longer seem to work.

I've tried adding both of the following (not at the same time) to App > Package Contents > Info.plist, then quitting and re-opening the app with no success.

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>

<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```